# Avoid multiple Not null statements

Tags: java, junit, refactoring

I have a Converter-Class, where I convert one object into another. There I have multiple if-statements, checking if a value is null. Now when Unit-Testing this of course means, that I need to test every if-condition, even though it's pretty simple. Here a simplified example:

```
public OutputData convert(InputData input){
    final OutputData output = new OutputData();

    output.setName(input.getName());
    output.setCity(input.getCity());
    if(isNotEmpty(input.getObjects())){
        output.setMainObject(input.getObjects().get(0));
    }

    if(input.getType() != null){
        output.setType(input.getType());
    }

    if(input.getID() != null){
        output.setId(input.getID());
    }

    return output;
}
```

Now keep in mind, there are like 4 to 5 more in my real project. So what would be a way to avoid it or ensure, that it's easier to test?

Comment: Is there a reason why you even _allow_ nulls in your `InputData` to begin with?

Comment: And to go on: What happens if the fields do not get set at all in contrast to setting them to null?

Comment: The question is: _Why are you null-checking?_ I mean, you simply could remove that null-checking code. Even if something is `null`, this value would simply be set over an already `null` value.

Comment: I'm not at all sure I'm clear on what you're asking. Are you asking how to modify the code above to avoid lots of `!= null` checks? Or how to *write new code* that tests the code above? If the latter, what's the question?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose They could be set to a default in the constructor. That's why I asked what happens if he just set them to null (see above).

Comment: Sorry I noticed I made a mistake, some brackets were missing. Well in general the fields ID and Type in this example can be null. So if I would then just set a field from output with null, I would get a NullPointerException

Comment: Erm, no, you won't. Just setting a field to null does not by itself result in a NPE. In the case when in the input the id field *is* null, then the field in the output won't be set. So what is it? Null? Or do you set it to a default in constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Optional but, like @Seelenvirtuose said, unless you're avoiding to override some default value your null check is preventing to set a value that is already null.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html